# Python cgi.FieldStorage not accepting spaces

Tags: python, json, cgi, url-encoding

I have a python script that is called from a php server ( using GET ).

The php scripts pass a json string to the python script

The Problem i am facing is cgi.FieldStorage is not accepting spaces between any "values" (from the "key":"value"). The string brakes at the space and i get an error for unended string ( as python does not get the ending " )

Could someone help me with how to solve this?

Comment: Did you url encode the query string, space → `%20` ??

Comment: @KlausD the problem with encoding it is, i dont want other things like " { etc to get % encoded... they are properly handled by escape using \

Comment: No, you can't escape spaces with `\` in URLs they have to be "URL encoded".